# Load opengl/directx API functions at runtime

Tags: c++, dll

I'm building an opengl/directx/vulkan modern game engine. I have previously written a version of the engine where I separated API specific code with macros, like:

```
#ifdef CIANADE_API_OGL
OGLTexture::GPU_LoadTexture();
#elif defined(CIANADE_API_DX12)
DX12Texture::GPU_LoadTexture();
#elif //etc....
```

and for each API **and** platform I had seperate builds (cianade_ogl4.exe, cianade_ogl3.exe, cianade_dx12.exe, etc...).
My question would be **is it possible and would it be a good idea** to load opengl and directx api functions **dynamically** at runtime (just for PC platforms, mobile/consoles would have only one executable) and if so, how could it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question **is is it possible and would it be a good idea** to load opengl and directx api functions **dynamically** at runtime (just for PC platforms, mobile/consoles would have only one executable) and if so, how could it be done ?

I'm not an expert for those graphic engines, but yes it's possible to load the underlying DLL's at runtime.

You'll need to provide wrapper interfaces for the specific library functions though:

```
struct IGraphLibTexture {
    virtual void GPU_LoadTexture() = 0;
    virtual ~IGraphLibTexture() {}
};
```

and provide different implementations in separate DLL's.

According to your target architecture determined at runtime, you load one of these DLL's explicitly then.

If that's actually a good idea I'll leave for others to answer.

Comment: Thanks :) Do you think that load time and call time could be an issue though ? A lot of functions might be called **once** or **twice** a frame (60 Hz).

Comment: Also what do you mean by "provide different implementations in separate DLLs" ?

Comment: @Coder32 Polymorphism and vtable introduction affect performance yes. But 60Hz isn't really a problem for most modern CPU's.

Comment: @Coder32 _"Also what do you mean ..."_ I meant you separate the implementation for `IGraphLibTexture` into their own DLLs, and one of these is loaded at runtime.